# How to access content from multiple files

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Is there any way that I can add the content of multiple files then put the combined values into one file?

I am currently trying this:

```
 $start_tr = include 'include_all_items/item_input_start_tr.php' ;   
 $img_start = include 'include_all_items/item_input_img_start.php' ;
 $img_link = include 'include_all_items/item_input_img_link.php' ;
 $img_end = include 'include_all_items/item_input_img_end.php' ;

 $newcontent = "$start_tr
 $link 
 $img_start 
 $_POST[img_link] 
 $img_end ";

 $content = $newcontent.file_get_contents('../../include/item.computer.php');
 file_put_contents('../../include/item.computer.php', $content);
```

Comment: What you are trying to do here?

Comment: :D put all include code in "allinc.php" then include that   singlr "allinc.php" - no other way that i know .... but what is this  >>> $start_tr = include  ; i am confused !

Comment: No that's just a made up tag. like $text or anything. look at Hanky 웃 Panky post. that's how you include a tag. I will take your advise inputting all includes in one file then put it into include. Thanks man :)

Comment: @AvrumiSherman You are misusing the term "include", which has a special meaning in PHP, and that is causing confusion. The advice about combining includes is not relevant to what you're trying to do... now that it is clear. I've edited your post to clarify the question for future visitors, and I'll leave my (now irrelevant) answer up, but for reference, check out what `include` means within PHP :)

Comment: Haha ok thanks for editing. but you just got more confused, the original question was ok. 
For my question i will try to re-explain it. i rely hope i can write it more clearly this time.  
So what i was trying to do is to create a file for example file.php and get include from another file (item_input_start_tr.php) to post some text into file.php.
anyway i hope that explains.
Dam i googled for the answer i culdint find anything, now that the answer is here i realized i posted my own question. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include` is for code, not for `content`. In your case you have to use `file_get_contents` so you can save the returned value. `include` will not give you that value.

**[include()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)**

> Handling Returns: include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1.

```
 $start_tr = file_get_contents('include_all_items/item_input_start_tr.php');   
 $img_start = file_get_contents('include_all_items/item_input_img_start.php');
 $img_link = file_get_contents('include_all_items/item_input_img_link.php');
 $img_end = file_get_contents('include_all_items/item_input_img_end.php');
```

Now you can use your variable like you did.

```
 $newcontent = "$start_tr
 $link 
 $img_start 
 $_POST[img_link] 
 $img_end ";
```

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` and `include` are two totally different tools. Be sure you make the distinction -- if you're adding more PHP script to the current script, you want include/require. If you're trying to get the contents of files into a variable, that's a whole different task.

Assuming you ARE trying to include/require PHP script, the solution to this is to either a) use an autoloader (preferred for classes) or b) place all your includes in a single file, and then include *that* file from your other scripts.

Single file method:

*common.php*

```
 include 'include_all_items/item_input_start_tr.php' ;   
 include 'include_all_items/item_input_img_start.php' ;
 include 'include_all_items/item_input_img_link.php' ;
 include 'include_all_items/item_input_img_end.php' ;
```

*myScript.php*

```
 include('common.php');
```

An autoloader is more complex, and I don't have enough details about your use case here to provide a relevant example. An example: https://gist.github.com/jwage/221634

Also, you're taking the return from calling include: `$start_tr = include 'include_all_items/item_input_start_tr.php';` -- unless you're doing something in those included files, the return of `include` is either false or 1. Per the manual:

> Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1

Finally, be sure you mean `include` rather than `require`!

**Documentation**

- `include` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php
- `require` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php
- Autoloading Classes - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php
- `spl_autoload_register` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: 1+ thanks for your awesome answer. Very detailed :) but i needed this  $img_end = file_get_contents('include_all_items/item_input_img_end.php'); I will take some things from your Document...

Comment: @AvrumiSherman right, as I mentioned above, I think there was some confusion about the word "include" -- it means something different in PHP than the simple English meaning :)

Comment: @AvrumiSherman -- and by the way, I don't care and I doubt Hanky 웃 Panky does either, BUT, to "+1" someone, you click the little up arrow to the left of the answer (or question). You should generally upvote the answer you choose, at least :)

Comment: I would of i cant just yet. i need at least 15 rep to do so. i currently have 5. just a fue more to go :)